# How to hide the vertical scrollbar only, but still allow scroll?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, scrollbar, react-window

I have 2 scrollable elements ( from react-window) side by side, that are "synchronized": scrolling one will make the other scroll too.

I would like to hide the vertical scrollbar of the left element so they appear as one single element, like a table. And let the scrollbar from the right element displayed.

Here is an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-fire-4j5ro

I cant use ::-webkit-scrollbar because it also hide the horizontal scrollbar, that I need to keep.

I tried this trick: [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll) but it seems not to work with react-window.

Does anyone have an idea for this use case ?

Thank you !

Comment: any solution you found ?

Comment: The only solution I found was to overlap the left <div> with the other <div>. You can position the right <div> so it hides the scollbar form the left <div>. You can use dom-helpers/util/scrollbarSize to get the correct size of your scrollbar, depending on the browser.